# Percentage Coverage in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have this value.counts() dataframe (already ascending) :

```
A 20
B 15
C 15
D 10
E 10
F 10
G  8
H  5
I  5
```

Then I want to get a first 70% for example, then what I get is

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

Do pandas have function for that ? I have tried with groupby but it does not work. Or should I code manually like with for loop or something ?

thanks

Find biggest coverage in percent with pandas from a dataframe.
Is there any shortcut function or should code manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming X, Y the column names, you can compare the [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to be lower or equal ([`le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html)) to 70, and slice with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df['Y'].cumsum().le(70), 'X']
```

Alternative by position (first and second column):

```
df.loc[df.iloc[:, 1].cumsum().le(70), df.columns[0]]
```

output:

```
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
Name: X, dtype: object
```

Used input:

```
   X   Y
0  A  20
1  B  15
2  C  15
3  D  10
4  E  10
5  F  10
6  G   8
7  H   5
8  I   5
9  G   2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That answer my question. Do you know if there is any function to summarize, ie. first 70 % is A,B,C,D,E (as you answered). Then last  20% is F,G (for example) and last 10% is I, J. ?

Comment: Can you open a new question with the details?

Comment: Any reason why you unaccepted the answer?